# Laravel - AJAX Search allow Multiple Filters to be applied

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a controller that works on an AJAX jQuery call when I need to search/filter the database:

```
$launchsitesatellite = DB::table('satellites')
->where(function($q) use ($request) {
    if(empty($request->type) && empty($request->rocket_type)) {
        $q->orWhere('satname','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
            ->orWhere('norad_cat_id','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
            ->orWhere('country','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%')
            ->orWhere('object_id','LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%');
    } else {
        if(!empty($request->type)) {
            $q->orWhere($request->type,'LIKE','%'.$request->search.'%');
        }
        if(!empty($request->object_type)) {
            $q->orWhere('object_type','LIKE','%'.$request->object_type.'%');
        }
        if(!empty($request->launch_year)) {
            $q->orWhere('launch','LIKE','%'.$request->launch_year.'%');
        }
    }
})
->where('site', $site_code)->Paginate(300);
```

This controller can search/filter my database with no problem. The only thing I would like to fix is to allow multiple filters to be applied. For example, currently when I filter by Object Type and then decide to filter by Country, it resets the Object Type.

What I want to be able to do is to allow it to filter by Object Type AND Country, not only one.

There was a lack of examples/documentation so I could not find any examples of how this is done.

EDIT: JS AJAX Call

```
$("#filter-type").change(function() {
$value=$(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "{{$launchsitename->site_code}}",
    data: {'search':$value, type:'object_type'},
    success: function(data){
      $('#launchsatdisplay').html(data);
    }
});
});
```

Comment: Have you considered using a search engine with Laravel Scout: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/scout?

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson I am using 5.4

Comment: Whats issue in current code?

Comment: @LakshayJain I am able to select one filter, but when I select a second filter, it resets the first one.

Comment: Looking at your code I don't see why using a second filter would **reset** the first one. It would mean that you'd see more results though because you're using `orWhere` or is this what you want?

Comment: @RossWilson I also don't really know why it would reset. I thought adding the filters into the `if` statement would make them work together, not reset onee another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the reason you're having this issue is because you're using `orWhere` rather than `where` so in theory the more filters you use the more results you will have returned (rather than limiting the results).

```
$launchsitesatellite = DB::table('satellites')
    ->where(function ($q) use ($request) {

        if (!$request->has('type') && !$request->has('rocket_type')) {
            $q->orWhere('satname', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')
                ->orWhere('norad_cat_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')
                ->orWhere('country', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%')
                ->orWhere('object_id', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%');
        } else {
            if ($request->has('type')) {
                $q->where($request->type, 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%');
            }
            if ($request->has('object_type')) {
                $q->where('object_type', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->object_type . '%');
            }
            if ($request->has('launch_year')) {
                $q->where('launch', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->launch_year . '%');
            }
        }
    })
    ->where('site', $site_code)
    ->Paginate(300);
```

Also, just FYI, Laravel Query Builder comes with a `when()` method which is an alternative to using multiple `if` statements. So the main `else` section would look like:

```
$q
    ->when($request->has('type'), function ($q) use ($request) {
        $q->where($request->type, 'LIKE', '%' . $request->search . '%');
    })
    ->when($request->has('object_type'), function ($q) use ($request) {
        $q->where('object_type', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->object_type . '%');
    })
    ->when($request->has('launch_year'), function ($q) use ($request) {
        $q->where('launch', 'LIKE', '%' . $request->launch_year . '%');
    });
```

Obviously, you don't have to do this though (I just thought I'd mention it).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Just tried it, but unfortunately the when I select a second filter, it resets the first one. I guess the `where()` does not fix the issue. BTW, thanks for telling me about the `when()` method. Never knew it existed!

Comment: @D.777KLM How are you selecting/submitting the filters? Are you just using links or is javascript involved as well? If it is javascript would you mind editing your question to show your js code?

Comment: I use a `select` to choose by what term I want filtered. I have posted the Javascript AJAX call in my question.

Comment: @D.777KLM You're only submitting one value at a time so yes it will reset every time.

Comment: So I guess that is the problem why. Then I need to figure out a way to save the first filter and not reset it when I submit a second one unless the user resets it.

Comment: @D.777KLM I would suggest either making your select multiple or using checkboxes (assuming you don't have that many).

Comment: I would be able to do checkboxs for one select as it only has three options, but my other select have quite a lot of options, so it would not be possible to be use select for them. I see what I can do.